# tf tree is invalide because it contains a loop

Tags: kinect, rviz, turtlebot, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to display my laserscan on rviz but its status flickers between Status:Ok and Status:Error because of Transform.

```
Transform [sender=/depthimage_to_laserscan]
For frame [camera_depth_frame]: No transform to fixed frame [base_footprint]. 
TF error: [The tf tree is invalid because it contains a loop. 
Frame camera_rgb_optical_frame exists with parent camera_rgb_frame. 
Frame camera_rgb_frame exists with parent base_link. 
Frame base_footprint exists with parent odom. 
Frame base_link exists with parent base_footprint. 
Frame left_cliff_sensor_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame leftfront_cliff_sensor_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame right_cliff_sensor_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame rightfront_cliff_sensor_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame wall_sensor_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame camera_depth_frame exists with parent camera_rgb_frame. 
Frame camera_depth_optical_frame exists with parent camera_depth_frame. 
Frame camera_link exists with parent camera_rgb_frame. 
Frame front_wheel_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame gyro_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame base_laser_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame laser exists with parent base_link. 
Frame plate_0_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame plate_1_link exists with parent plate_0_link. 
Frame plate_2_link exists with parent plate_1_link. 
Frame plate_3_link exists with parent plate_2_link. 
Frame rear_wheel_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame spacer_0_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame spacer_1_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame spacer_2_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame spacer_3_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame standoff_2in_0_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame standoff_2in_1_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame standoff_2in_2_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame standoff_2in_3_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame standoff_2in_4_link exists with parent standoff_2in_0_link. 
Frame standoff_2in_5_link exists with parent standoff_2in_1_link. 
Frame standoff_2in_6_link exists with parent standoff_2in_2_link. 
Frame standoff_2in_7_link exists with parent standoff_2in_3_link. 
Frame standoff_8in_0_link exists with parent standoff_2in_4_link. 
Frame standoff_8in_1_link exists with parent standoff_2in_5_link. 
Frame standoff_8in_2_link exists with parent standoff_2in_6_link. 
Frame standoff_8in_3_link exists with parent standoff_2in_7_link. 
Frame standoff_kinect_0_link exists with parent plate_2_link. 
Frame standoff_kinect_1_link exists with parent plate_2_link. 
Frame left_wheel_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame right_wheel_link exists with parent base_link. 
Frame scan1 exists with parent cart_frame. 
Frame scan2 exists with parent cart_frame. ]
```

How do I get rid of the error?

EDIT:

tf frames

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193469/tf-tree-is-invalide-because-it-contains-a-loop/) by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-09-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-25**:
Please share frame.pdf screenshot from `rosrun tf view_frames`

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-09-26**:
I've updated the question with my frames.

Ignore the cart_frame, that's something else that I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can be also caused by openni_launch node if you leave default settings and publish_tf over your urdf model. Set "arg publish_tf" to false in your launch file. Helped in my case.

```
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch" >
    <arg name="publish_tf" value="false" />
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [Frantisek.Durovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/19768/frantisek.durovsky/) with karma: 58 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2015-03-03**:
worked for me too! thank you :)

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2016-12-07**:
me too!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, this means you have a cycle in your tf *tree*. A tree is comprised of nodes, each with exactly one parent. The relationship is *directed*. A simple situation causing a loop would be with three nodes (a, b, c), where a is child of b, b is child of c, and c is child of a.

Chances are you mixed up the parent-child relationship somewhere in your config.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3